# Using Mapzen tiles with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapzen

My reading of the Leaflet and [Mapzen](https://mapzen.com/projects/vector-tiles/) documentations suggest that in order to use a custom tile provider with Leaflet, one needs to do just two things:

1. Specify the tile provider in `L.tilelayer(urlTemplateToTileProvider)`
2. Set this provider to MapZen

```js
var urlTemplateToTileProvider =
  'http://tile.mapzen.com/mapzen/vector/v1/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt?api_key=apiKey'
```

However, when I try this I end up with an empty map which then proceeds to display markers etc correctly.  And yet a manual test for a generated tile URL, e.g.

`http://tile.mapzen.com/mapzen/vector/v1/all/14/8471/5583.mvt?api_key=apiKey`

did in fact download some - unintelligible to me - data.

I also tried using the other two formats mentioned in the Mapzen docs (`.json` and `.geojson`) but with exactly the same result.  Given that the latter two formats return human readable data, I checked them out for my test tile in my browser and the data is indeed for the area I want to use.

Curiously enough, the Leaflet docs and tutorials request a PNG tile layer (`http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`), not raw data.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Tile Layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tilelayer) is for **raster** tiles (i.e. plain images, like the PNG format for example).

Mapzen delivers **vector** tiles. To use them with Leaflet, you could use a plugin, e.g. [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) ([license](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid#legalese))

> Display gridded vector data (sliced GeoJSON or protobuf vector tiles) in Leaflet 1.0.0

See the [demo](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/demo-vectortiles.html), which includes tiles from Mapzen

```js
var mapzenTilesUrl = "https://tile.mapzen.com/mapzen/vector/v1/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt?api_key={apikey}";
var mapzenVectorTileOptions = {
  rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
  attribution: '<a href="https://mapzen.com/">&copy; MapZen</a>, <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">&copy; OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  vectorTileLayerStyles: vectorTileStyling,
  apikey: 'KEY',
};
var mapzenTilesPbfLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(mapzenTilesUrl, mapzenVectorTileOptions);
```

Since you have raw data in the vector tiles, you need to provide the styling spec ([`vectorTileStyling`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/blob/13315057d285bfa5d5cb74d2abb442e925825b55/docs/demo-vectortiles.html#L30-L212))