# Cannot render vector tiles (.mbtiles) file with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geospatial, tiles, vector-graphics

I am trying to render some locally-stored and vector-based tiles download from OpenMapTile. The reason I am doing that is because my end application will only run on a computer that cannot be connected to the internet.

I have read many different things on whether or not leaflet can render vector-based tiles but it seems that it can from some examples.

[It seems that it is not possible with Vector Grid that only does raster tiles](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) but that [it is possible with Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles)

So I tried to do just that but always stumble upon an empty page when trying it out... I have the controllers for the map but it just doesn't display anything. Here is my MWE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>VectorGrid.Protobuf example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />

</head>
<body style='margin:0'>

    <div id="map" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: white"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@1.2.0"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sql.js@0.3.2/js/sql.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.tilelayer.mbtiles@latest/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles.js"></script>-->
    <script src="Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles.js"></script>


    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script> -->
    <script>

            var vectorTileStyling = {

            water: {
                fill: true,
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#06cccc',
                color: '#06cccc',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4,
            },
            admin: {
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: 'pink',
                color: 'pink',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            waterway: {
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#2375e0',
                color: '#2375e0',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            landcover: {
                fill: true,
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#53e033',
                color: '#53e033',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4,
            },
            landuse: {
                fill: true,
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#e5b404',
                color: '#e5b404',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            park: {
                fill: true,
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#84ea5b',
                color: '#84ea5b',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            boundary: {
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#c545d3',
                color: '#c545d3',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            aeroway: {
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#51aeb5',
                color: '#51aeb5',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            road: { // mapbox & nextzen only
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#f2b648',
                color: '#f2b648',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            tunnel: {   // mapbox only
                weight: 0.5,
                fillColor: '#f2b648',
                color: '#f2b648',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4,
//                  dashArray: [4, 4]
            },
            bridge: {   // mapbox only
                weight: 0.5,
                fillColor: '#f2b648',
                color: '#f2b648',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4,
//                  dashArray: [4, 4]
            },
            transportation: {   // openmaptiles only
                weight: 0.5,
                fillColor: '#f2b648',
                color: '#f2b648',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4,
//                  dashArray: [4, 4]
            },
            transit: {  // nextzen only
                weight: 0.5,
                fillColor: '#f2b648',
                color: '#f2b648',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4,
//                  dashArray: [4, 4]
            },
            building: {
                fill: true,
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#2b2b2b',
                color: '#2b2b2b',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            water_name: {
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#022c5b',
                color: '#022c5b',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            transportation_name: {
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#bc6b38',
                color: '#bc6b38',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            place: {
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#f20e93',
                color: '#f20e93',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            housenumber: {
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#ef4c8b',
                color: '#ef4c8b',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            poi: {
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#3bb50a',
                color: '#3bb50a',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },
            earth: {    // nextzen only
                fill: true,
                weight: 1,
                fillColor: '#c0c0c0',
                color: '#c0c0c0',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                opacity: 0.4
            },


            // Do not symbolize some stuff for mapbox
            country_label: [],
            marine_label: [],
            state_label: [],
            place_label: [],
            waterway_label: [],
            poi_label: [],
            road_label: [],
            housenum_label: [],


            // Do not symbolize some stuff for openmaptiles
            country_name: [],
            marine_name: [],
            state_name: [],
            place_name: [],
            waterway_name: [],
            poi_name: [],
            road_name: [],
            housenum_name: [],
        };


        // Monkey-patch some properties for nextzen layer names, because
        // instead of "building" the data layer is called "buildings" and so on
        vectorTileStyling.buildings  = vectorTileStyling.building;
        vectorTileStyling.boundaries = vectorTileStyling.boundary;
        vectorTileStyling.places     = vectorTileStyling.place;
        vectorTileStyling.pois       = vectorTileStyling.poi;
        vectorTileStyling.roads      = vectorTileStyling.road;



        var map = L.map('map');


        //var openmaptilesUrl = "https://free-{s}.tilehosting.com/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf.pict?key={key}";
        var openmaptilesUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/2017-07-03_france_toulouse.mbtiles";



        var openmaptilesVectorTileOptions = {
            rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
            attribution: '<a href="https://openmaptiles.org/">&copy; OpenMapTiles</a>, <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">&copy; OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            vectorTileLayerStyles: vectorTileStyling,
            subdomains: '0123',
            key: 'UmmATPUongHdDmIicgs7',
            maxZoom: 14
        };

        var mb = L.tileLayer.mbTiles(openmaptilesUrl).addTo(map);
        /*var openmaptilesPbfLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(openmaptilesUrl, openmaptilesVectorTileOptions).addTo(map);*/


        map.setView({ lat: 47.040182144806664, lng: 9.667968750000002 }, 0);


        /*L.control.layers({
            OpenMapTiles: openmaptilesPbfLayer,
        }, {}, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);*/




    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since I had trouble finding Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles, `https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles/blob/master/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles.js` is a version that you can download

As for an example tile, you can use [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yVNG5x7Rm2n7c7dll9iyqOBCPp4oFhtx/view?usp=sharing) (directly downloaded from OpenMapTiles focusing on France's Toulouse as it was a rather smaller mbtile file).

I really don't understand what the problem is. It came to my mind that it could very well be that leaflet cannot read vector tiles, in which case I thought that I could try to convert them so that I end up with raster tiles, but I could not find a way to do so. I don't know what the best solution could be... It seems that some people have managed to make it work with vector AND raster tiles [as explained on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175582/possible-to-style-mbtiles-in-a-leaflet-map) but I just can't seem to find a way to make it work on my own and this linked post is not very detailed.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
var openmaptilesUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/2017-07-03_france_toulouse.mbtiles";
```

for this:

```
var openmaptilesUrl = "./2017-07-03_france_toulouse.mbtiles";
```

and store your mbtiles file to root of your web next to index.html